# Entity Framework 6.0 and Mysql giving error in Bulk update

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a project that runs using the MySql DBMS, however I had to upgrade the project to the Entity Framework 6.0 due to some Bulk Insert functions and Bulk Update, but now every time I'll try to do some update in the database, it gives the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ' [relatoriocredito_debug]. [tb_pagar] SET \r\n [pag_baixado] =
>   's ', \r\n [pag_databaixa] ' at line 1

What I understand is that he is using the syntax of Microsoft SQL Server and MYSQL, not as I do for him to use the MySQL syntax?

The connector that I am using is the latest version, just below is also my app.config

```
<? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"? >
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  <!--For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit-http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468->
    <section name = "entityFramework" type = "system.data. Entity. Internal. ConfigFile. EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version 6.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission = "false"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name = "relatoriocredito_debugEntities" connectionString = "metadata = res://*/res://*/Mappings.EF.ssdl Mappings.EF.csdl | | */res://Mappings.EF.msl; provider = MySql.Data.MySqlClient; provider connection string = server = &quot; 10.32.71.77; user id = * * * * * * *;p assword = *** * * * * *;p ersistsecurityinfo = True; database = relatoriocredito_debug; allowuservariables = True providerName =" &quot; "/" System.Data.EntityClient >
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityframework>
    <defaultconnectionfactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" >
      <parameters>
        <parameter value = "mssqllocaldb"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblybinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentassembly>
        <assemblyidentity name = "EntityFramework" publicKeyToken = "b77a5c561934e089" culture = "neutral"/>
        <bindingredirect oldVersion = "0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion = "6.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```